# Change input stype and style in configuration page (for module) in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Can we change the style of an input in configuration page for my module, I used this tutorial for creating my module page configuration :

- [Adding configuration page](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Adding+a+configuration+page)
- [Making your module work with Bootstrap](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Making+your+module+work+with+Bootstrap)

as you see in the tutorial the type of the input is 'text' and I want to change it, for exemple I want to have input 'date', like the default input date of prestashop 1.6 :
i.stack.imgur.com/9OcBC.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem resolved !! you need just to add datepicker in class of the input :

```
 array( 
'type' =>'text',
'label' => $this->l('Date : '),
'name' => 'date',
'class' => 'datepicker fixed-width-xxl',
'required' => true )
```